# {cases} argument not running, rather says fraction has an extra '}'?

Tags: errors, cases, debugging

What is wrong with this piece of code in Latex?

```
$$\begin{displaystyle} 
C =\begin{cases} 
\frac{4}{3}, &(\text{for color singlet configuration}) \\
 -\frac{1}{6}, &(\text{for color octet configuration}) 
\end{cases} 
\end{displaystyle}$$
```

The compiler shows this error:

[image]

How should I correct this?

Comment: you have omitted the `amsmath` package (most likely) but what is the intention of `\begin{displaystyle}` here `\displaystyle` isn't needed and is never intended as an environment)

Comment: Works fine for me in a MWE. Are you loading amsmath? Btw: You shouldn't use `$$\begin{displaystyle}`, use `\[` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error from

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{displaystyle} 
C =\begin{cases} 
\frac{4}{3}, &(\text{for color singlet configuration}) \\
 -\frac{1}{6}, &(\text{for color octet configuration}) 
\end{cases} 
\end{displaystyle}$$
\end{document}
```

But the markup should be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
C =\begin{cases} 
\frac{4}{3}, &(\text{for color singlet configuration}) \\
 -\frac{1}{6}, &(\text{for color octet configuration}) 
\end{cases} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would probably add a `\phantom{-}` before the first \frac.

Comment: Writing `\hfill` before the first `\frac` works too. :-)